# How to set default language for Mathematica 8's DictionaryLookup

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 8's `DictionaryLookup` function uses `"English"` as the language by default. Is there any way to set the default language to `"BritishEnglish"` or `"Spanish"`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be an option for this, but you can modify the definition of `DictionaryLookup` to suit you.

The method I will use relies on the automatic ordering of DownValues and was written for version 7 so it may need adjustment.  You can look at `DownValues[DictionaryLookup]` to see how the function is written as it is top-level *Mathematica* code.

```
$dictionaryLanguage = "Spanish";

Unprotect[DictionaryLookup];

DictionaryLookup[pat : Except[_List], x___] /;
  ! TrueQ[$dicLang] && ValueQ[$dictionaryLanguage] :=
 Block[{$dicLang = True},
  DictionaryLookup[{$dictionaryLanguage, pat}, x]
  ]

DownValues[DictionaryLookup] = 
  RotateRight @ DownValues[DictionaryLookup];

Protect[DictionaryLookup];
```

With this definition, if `$dictionaryLanguage` is set that value will be used for the language.  You can restore default behavior with `$dictionaryLanguage =.`.  Examples:

```
$dictionaryLanguage = "Spanish";

DictionaryLookup["*orac*", 3]
```

> {"adoración", "aminoración", "colaboración"}

```
$dictionaryLanguage =.;

DictionaryLookup["*orac*", 3]
```

> {"coracle", "coracles", "Horace"}

Know that you call also do look-ups outside of `DictionaryLookup`.  You can load the dictionary for a language like this:

```
DataPaclets`Dictionary`ReloadDictionary["Dutch"]
```

Which places the data in `` DataPaclets`Dictionary`$Dictionary ``.  An example search:

```
Pick[#, # ~StringMatchQ~ "*fzand*"] ~Take~ 4 & @ DataPaclets`Dictionary`$Dictionary
```

> {"afzand", "afzandde", "afzandden", "afzanderij"}

The equivalent `DictionaryLookup` query:

```
DictionaryLookup[{"Dutch", "*fzand*"}, 4]
```

> {"afzand", "afzandde", "afzandden", "afzanderij"}

If you use these tools often you could them in the context path with:

```
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "DataPaclets`Dictionary`"]
```

Then you could use `ReloadDictionary` and `$Dictionary` as is, without the context name.